# How to efficiently extract date year from dataframe header in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The objective is to extract df under the month-year category while omitting other.
The code below one way how this objective can be achieved

```
df = DataFrame ( [['PP1', 'LN', 'T1', 'C11', 'C21', 'C31', 'C32']] )
df.columns =['dummy1','dummy2', 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb 2080','Dec 1993']
extract_header_name=list(df.columns.values)
lookup_list= ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar','Apr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
month_year_list=[i for e in lookup_list for i in extract_header_name if e in i]
```

Output

```
['Jan-20', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb-20', 'Feb 2080', 'Dec 1993']
```

However, I wonder if is another efficient or pandas built module to achieve similar result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with values joined by `|` for regex `or` - it means `Jan` or `Feb`... and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with `df.columns`:

```
month_year_list = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(lookup_list))].tolist()
print (month_year_list)
['Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb 2080', 'Dec 1993']
```

Or use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with convert list to tuple:

```
month_year_list = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith(tuple(lookup_list))].tolist()
```

Another idea if only this 2 formats of datetimes:

```
s = df.columns.to_series()
s1 = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b-%y', errors='coerce')
s2 = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b %Y', errors='coerce')
month_year_list = df.columns[s1.fillna(s2).notna()].tolist()
print (month_year_list)
['Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb 2080', 'Dec 1993']
```

Comment: Yes, this much more compact that what I have originally. awesome

Answer (score 1):

Select columns using `df.filter` and extract their names.

```
list(df.filter(regex='|'.join(lookup_list)).columns)

['Jan-20', 'Feb-20', 'Jan 2021', 'Feb 2080', 'Dec 1993']
```